# Write in the end of a file on ubuntu server using ssh.net

Tags: c#, ubuntu, sftp, streamwriter, ssh.net

I want to add some lines to `\etc\ssh\sshd_config` using ssh.net, I have tried this method
`SFTPCLient.WriteAllLines(string path, string[] content)` but it adds the `content` at the beginning of the file after deleting the same number of lines. In the documentation I've found this  `It is not first truncated to zero bytes.` what does it mean?
I've tried also this method  `public abstract void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);`  with another file, because I didn't want to risque deleting other lines, BUT it doesn't work, can anyone explain the values that the offset and the count must take?

```
string[] config = {"Match user Fadwa", "ChrootDirectory /fadwa/dhifi/test",
    "ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /fadwa"};

byte[] bconfig = config.SelectMany(s =>Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s + 
    Environment.NewLine)).ToArray();
Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpFileStream stream = sftpClient.OpenWrite("/sftp/dhifi/test.txt");
if (stream.CanWrite)
{
    stream.Write(bconfig,0,bconfig.Length);
}
else Console.WriteLine("Can't Write right now ! ");
```

Else, any other solution is welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you misspell length? bconfig.Lenght

Comment: @jdweng just misspelled here (I've fixed it) , I've compiled the code already , it works fine but without writing anything in the real file.

Comment: You have to move to end of file before writing.

Comment: @BACON `SftpClient.AppendAllLines()` works for me, thx a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SftpClient.OpenWrite()` [creates a `Stream`](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/031f0a164be341ea0de90919922cc825300fd776/src/Renci.SshNet/SftpClient.cs#L1406) positioned at the beginning of the file.  "It is not first truncated to zero bytes" means that `Stream` will *not*  be writing into what is effectively an empty file, but instead overwriting the existing bytes of the file.  Thus, if the existing file is longer than the `content` parameter of `SftpFileStream.Write()`, the resulting file will consist of `content` followed by the remainder of the existing file, which is exactly what you observed.

Looking at [the documentation](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/releases/download/2016.1.0/SSH.NET-2016.1.0-help.chm) I see a few solutions:

- `SftpClient.AppendAllLines()`:

  ```cs
  sftpClient.AppendAllLines("/sftp/dhifi/test.txt", config);
  ```
- `SftpClient.AppendText()`:

  ```cs
  using (StreamWriter writer = sftpClient.AppendText("/sftp/dhifi/test.txt"))
      foreach (string line in config)
          writer.WriteLine(line);
  ```
- Since you want to start writing at the end of the file, instead of `SftpClient.OpenWrite()` you can call `SftpClient.Open()`, which allows you to specify a [`FileMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode) of `Append`:

  ```cs
  using (SftpFileStream stream = sftpClient.Open("/sftp/dhifi/test.txt", FileMode.Open | FileMode.Append))
      stream.Write(bconfig, 0, bconfig.Length);
  ```

  I don't believe your check of `CanWrite` is necessary because the `Stream` should fail to open in the first place if `FileAccess.Write` could not be granted.

  If `FileMode.Append` for some reason doesn't work with SSH.NET (and it looks like it does since that's [what `AppendText()` uses](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/031f0a164be341ea0de90919922cc825300fd776/src/Renci.SshNet/SftpClient.cs#L1144)) you could instead use [@jdweng's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62519073/write-in-the-end-of-a-file-on-ubuntu-server-using-ssh-net#comment110564728_62519073) and seek to the end of the file before writing to it:

  ```cs
  using (SftpFileStream stream = sftpClient.OpenWrite("/sftp/dhifi/test.txt"))
  {
      stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
      stream.Write(bconfig, 0, bconfig.Length);
  }
  ```

As an aside, another way to inject `NewLine`s between your `config` lines would be...

```cs
byte[] bconfig = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
    string.Join(Environment.NewLine, config)
);
```

That's a little shorter and more efficient since it reduces the number of intermediate `string`s and `byte[]`s.